# Create a new object instead of updating the current one using SimpleForm simple_fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, nested-form-for

I have the following nested form in my `product_models/new.html.erb`

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :product_category do |g| %>
    <%= g.input :name, placeholder: "Category name", label: "Category", disabled: true, input_html: {id: "new_product_category_input", style: "width: 300px"} %>
<% end %>
```

Is there any way I can make the form create the object instead of updating the current one?

Inspecting the generated html, it is possible to see that simple form adds a hidden field with the "id" value of the existing `product_category`. Removing this field, everything works. But I do not know how to do it =/

---

product_category
- :id
- :name

Comment: What do you mean by *"updating the current one"* ? if you are on a "New" form, it's for create a new object, association included

Comment: I do actually want to create a new object in the `new`/`edit` forms.

Comment: but if you go on "New" route, the `create` action is called on submit, not `update` (even if `new` and `edit` share the same form partial), so i still don't see what you mean by "updating the current one"

Comment: I have a `Product` that has a `ProductModel` field. `ProductModel` has a `ProductCategory` field. I want, in the new/edit form of the `Product`, to give user the option to select an already existing `ProductCategory` or create a new one, by filling an input text field. It is possible to edit the `ProductModel` in the `Product` form.

Comment: maybe you should edit your question because you say : "I have the following nested form in my **`product_models/new.html.erb`**" and add some more code of your form because it's a little bit confusing